# Help me identify this set? Rocky terrain with castle walls?

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

My brother has handed down some of his old LEGO to my kids . He had sets including Star Wars, Harry Potter, generic Lego, Batman, and Lord of Rings collected between the years 2006 and 2013.

These pretty unique pieces were in the box, and I feel like they are Lord of the Rings. However, I can’t find any sets that have pieces like these.

Any LEGO fans know what set this may be? I have tried using few sites to look up individual parts in hopes of finding the set, but no luck thus far.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think any of this is Lego , except the manual. These are probaly  Megablocks

Answer (score 8):

From the Megablok wiki:

[9650 Raiders Keep](http://www.blokcity.com/wiki/9650_Raiders_Keep)

[image]